# I used self.transport.write function to write to tcp stream, How to use flush with it?

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I created a simple tcp connection server with Twisted framework. I use the `self.transport.write` function to write data to the client, but I need to flush the data. Is there a way to do this? In addition, is there a way to flush incoming data?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need and no way to flush either the read buffer or the write buffer.

Comment: I think I saw there is a method with stdout -> stdout.flush(). So isn't nothing like that with twisted framework?

Comment: That's what "no way to flush" means, yes.  Fortunately, as I mentioned, there is also no need.